# How does $\int dz \,d\bar z$ evaluate to $\int\int dx \,dy$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

While asking us to prove this relation:

$$\int dz\,d\bar{z} e^{-\bar{z}wz} = \frac{\pi}{w}$$

our professor gave us this statement:

> In the above equation the measure $\int dz\,d\bar{z}$ actually stands for $\int dR[z]dI[z] = \int\int dxdy$, the limits running from −∞ to +∞.

Given this statement, I find that proving the relation is quite easy. However, I am unable to evaluate $\int dz\,d\bar{z}$ to obtain $\int\int dxdy$. Any pointers in understanding this would be of great help.

Edit:
I am assuming that $w$ is a real positive integer.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your professor is off by a factor of $i/2$. What's actually going on is differential forms. We have $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z=x-iy$, so
\begin{align*}
dz &= dx + i\,dy \\
d\bar z &= dx - i\,dy,
\end{align*}
from which we get
$$dz\wedge d\bar z = (dx+i\,dy)\wedge (dx-i\,dy) = -2i dx\wedge dy.$$
(Remember that $\wedge$ is anti-commutative, so $dx\wedge dx = dy\wedge dy = 0$ and $dx\wedge dy = -dy\wedge dx$.)
You can see that this "fudge factor" is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the change of coordinates. At any rate, the correct formula is
$$\tfrac i2 dz\, d\bar z = dx\, dy.$$

Comment: Ted Shifirin. Thanks for the quick response. Could you please explain the meaning of $dz \wedge d\bar{z}$. I have a very limited knowledge of complex analysis.

Comment: Also, if it's not much of a trouble, could you please guide me through how we can solve the given integral?

Comment: You said you had no problem with the integral. The given integral does not converge. Do you want to double-check? If you have $e^{-a|z|^2}$ with $a$ positive and real, then this is a classic integral that you can do by switching to polar coordinates.

Comment: Well, I was able to solve the integral assuming that $\int dz d\bar{z} = \iint dx dy$. Now, if I am to write $dzd\bar{z} = -2idxdy$, then I realized that I end up with quantity $2i$ 'extra'. This is the part that is bothering me.

Comment: Well, I think your professor is just telling you something incorrect. But I have no idea how you're evaluating the integral.

Comment: Ted Shifrin Thank you. I realized that the integral I had typed in was missing a minus sign in the exponential. Now it should be fine. I intended to solve the intergal by taking $z = x + iy$. This simplifies the exponential to $e^{-w(x^2+y^2)}$ making the integral $2i\int e^{-wx^2}dx\int e^{-wy^2}dy$. This is a gaussian integral - evaluating this gives me $2i\frac{\pi}{w}$, which as I said, is larger by a factor of $2i$

Comment: You're assuming $w$ is a positive real number, not a general complex number?

Comment: Well, yes. I am considering that $w$ is a positive real number.

Comment: That should have been made explicit in your post. As I said twice, your professor is *incorrectly* ignoring the $-2i$ factor.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the post to state $w$ is a real positive number. And thanks for your comments. I did take it point-blank that the given integral is correct. I will clarify with my professor and get back. :)

Comment: I discussed this with my professor. He told, "for this exercise, we will simply define $\int dz^{*}dz = \iint dRe[z]dIm[z] = \iint dx dy$"